# I already have an RDS (Mysql) database with EC2, do I have to create a new one for elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am really frustrated in trying to figure out how to connect my already existing RDS mysql instance, that I use with my ec2 to my newly created elastic beanstalk environment. I don't understand why EB wants me to create a new one when I already have one. Can anyone please advise?

Answer (score 0):

No you don't have to create a new one. You just need to open the RDS security group to allow the Elastic Beanstalk instances to connect, and set an environment variable in the Elastic Beanstalk environment with the URL of the RDS server.